# Getting error while installing R packages?

Tags: r, package, updates, libraries, install.packages

It has been awhile since i updated my packages. This morning when i tried to used `update.packages(ask = F)`, it download the packages and tried to run the update but has spit out a number of warnings. see some glimpses here

```
> update.packages(ask = FALSE)

  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
          binary source needs_compilation
backports  1.1.7  1.1.9              TRUE
maptools   1.0-1  1.0-2              TRUE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/backports_1.1.7.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 81641 bytes (79 KB)
downloaded 79 KB

package ‘backports’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package ‘dplyr’
Warning: restored ‘dplyr’
```

Not sure what happened but when i am trying to load the package i am getting message such as the one attached as picture. Anyway forward please as it seems i have lost everything.
[image]

Comment: What version of R are you running? You can tell by print `R.version.string` in the console. Seems like you might be running 4.0.0. I suggest you update to 4.0.2. I've seen DLL errors before due to differences between these versions. Also the "cannot remove prior installation" means you might need to restart R and run the update command before you run any commands or reload previous workspaces to make sure the package can be replaced. Verify that you don't have multiple copes of R running.

Comment: Can't you run from the command line? `Rscript --vanilla -e "update.packages(ask = FALSE)"`.

Comment: Many thanks- there were multiple things. I had multiple version installed plus i do not have admin privileges to update. So with the help of our organization IT, i uninstalled all the older version, updated R first, and then updated the packages. problem solved.